# EF core code first not creating tables in Azure SQL database

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

I have been following this example (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) however when I start the project the database is automatically created just fine, but no tables are generated in the Azure SQL database. Will add code if required but I wonder if someone has run into this before and can easily answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to resolve this myself:

From the Tools menu, select NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console.
At the command line I used the following commands:

1. add-migration InitialCreate
2. Update-Database